# encrypting jquery .load() function

Tags: php, jquery

I'm calling a php page using .load()

`.load('page.php?user='+user+'&page='+page)`

if you go to the actual page.php and type `page.php?user=1&page=2`
you get the same result, how could I stop this from happening?
encrypting data maybe?

Could someone point me in the right direction, cheers.

@lonesomeday,

this answer works for me, yours was correct though:

`if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') { it's an ajax request validate id and continue! } else { this is not an ajax request, get out of here! }`

submitted by "ifaour"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately, anything that is accessible using AJAX is accessible without using AJAX.  That's the nature of the web.

You can **try** to ensure AJAX by checking for the XMLHTTPRequest header, but be aware that it can trivially be spoofed by a user who wants to:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] === 'XMLHTTPRequest') {
    // is probably an AJAX request
}
```

If you are making your request with jQuery, this should be safe, because jQuery adds this header itself. Be aware, though, that some browsers do not add it automatically if you are creating the XMLHTTPRequest object yourself.